# crm dynamics 2011 add a new value to dropdown list and set default value

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I cannot find how to add a country to drop down menu when creating account, lead or contact. At the moment I see only 2 countries. I need to add one more and make it as default one. So when I create lead, contact or account I don't need to choose every time. I have all the rights but no knowledge.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Click on the  `Customize` tab on the top of form ribbon and then select the `Form` option.
2. Form will open in edit mode, double click on country field and on new window select the  `Details` tab.
3. Click on Edit button, a new window will open
4. Add new option by clicking on the green colour plus button (pointed out in screenshot below).
5. Select the default country from default value drop down (pointed out in screenshot below).
6. Save and close the Field window
7. Save and Publish the form.
8. You are ready to go.

[image]

Comment: Hello, after ten years; I have a question; Can we add country list or something else by importing from Excel, extc. Because I need to add 80 new entry at once.